# CannotStartContainerError with node:6.7.0-wheezy on AWS

Tags: docker, npm, amazon-ecs

When I try to run my container in ECS I am getting the error

> CannotStartContainerError: API error (404): invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\"npm\\": executable file not found in $PATH\"\n"

This container's base is node:6.7.0-wheezy so I am not understanding how exactly it can be unable to find npm. Any ideas as to what I might be missing here?

Comment: This doesn't seem like an ECS error, are you sure the container runs locally when given the exact same commands/mounts/etc as you're providing when attempting to run on ECS?

Comment: Yup. I'd even tested doing it on another ECS cluster first. It was a weird error that only happened through the web interface. There error doesn't happen when I use the CLI instead. Ergo, I'm sticking to that.